# Nodejs + jsdom module, Error Object #<Object> has no method '$'

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, jsdom

I am attempting to make a simple nodejs client that will eventually crawl a given reddit users profile history. Right now i am trying to use the jsdom module to extract the URL for the next page of results on a given users profile.

I am currently working in ubuntu 12.10 and my versions of npm and nodejs are current.

Here is the code that i have so far.  I will include the error message below.

```
var http = require('http'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

//object containing http.request options
//path accepts a username via process.argv[2]
var options = {
    host: 'www.reddit.com',
    path: '/user/' + process.argv[2]
};

//getPage requests the page for a given user
function getPage() {

    var req = http.request(options, function(response){
        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on('data', function(rawHTML){
            // console.log(data);
            setNextPage(rawHTML);
        });
        response.on('error', function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
        response.on('end', function(){
            console.log('Response complete');
        });
    });

    req.end();
}

//the setNextPage function combs the rawHTML sent to it,
//extracting the URL for the next page of a users history

function setNextPage(rawHTML) {
    jsdom.env(
        rawHTML,
        ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        function(errors, window) {
            var nextPageURL = window.$(".nextprev > a").attr("href");
            console.log('URL for the next page is: ' + nextPageURL);
        }
    );
}

getPage();
```

Now for the error message that i am getting after running the client.

```
/home/stephen/Desktop/getKarma/app.js:38
            var nextPageURL = window.$('.nextprev > a').attr("href");
                                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$'
    at /home/stephen/Desktop/getKarma/app.js:38:29
    at exports.env.exports.jsdom.env.scriptComplete (/home/stephen/Desktop/getKarma/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:205:39)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Comment: Didn't run on Ubuntu, but I didn't get an error running that. I just got "URL for next page is: undefined". Try logging out the `errors` argument. I suspect that for whatever reason, the jQuery dependency isn't loading for you.

Comment: @IsaacCambron
Okay, so i logged the errors argument and was provided with a bit more information, though i'm still not sure what it's referring to.

New bit of error message says..

[ 'Cannot call method \'appendChild\' of null' ]

Comment: Ah, it wasn't working for me, either; I was just forgetting to put in the command-line argument and getting back a bogus page. It looks to me that you're not getting back the full page in rawHTML, and then you're getting bitten by https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/389

Comment: @IsaacCambron This looks like my issue. Thanks! Perhaps I need to buffer the entire page before trying to parse it with jsdom?

Comment: @IsaacCambron Yep that was it.  I buffered the entire page before sending it to jsdom and it worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.

Comment: You can just `npm install jquery` if you want to use jQuery w/ node.js

Comment: @Haocheng the jquery node module depends on jsdom, so it wouldn't make much difference in this case, and would actually be using more dependencies, not fewer.

Comment: @PeterLyons With package `jquery`, you can just use `var $ = require('jquery')` without considering `jsdom`.